# Python: Where does if-endif-statement end?

Tags: python, vb.net, vb6, migration

I have the following code:

```
for i in range(0,numClass):
    if breaks[i] == 0:
        classStart = 0
    else:
        classStart = dataList.index(breaks[i])
        classStart += 1
classEnd = dataList.index(breaks[i+1])

classList = dataList[classStart:classEnd+1]

classMean = sum(classList)/len(classList)
print classMean
preSDCM = 0.0
for j in range(0,len(classList)):
    sqDev2 = (classList[j] - classMean)**2
    preSDCM += sqDev2

SDCM += preSDCM
return (SDAM - SDCM)/SDAM
```

I would like to convert this code to VB.NET.

But I am not sure where the if-elseif-statement ends.
Does it end after "classStart += 1"?

I feel it a bit difficult to see where the for-next-loops end as well in Python.

The code is taken from http://danieljlewis.org/files/2010/06/Jenks.pdf

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. Python uses indentation to mark blocks. Both the `if` and the `for` end there.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Can you also tell me what the double asterisk (**) means in this line? sqDev2 = (classList[j]-classMean)**2

Comment: means "power of", equivalent to ^ in many languages.  **2 (squared), **3 (cubic)

Comment: It means "power", or what in some languages is `^` (Python uses that for bitwise xor).

Answer (score 11):

In Python, where your indented block ends, that is exactly where your block will end. So, for example, consider a bit simpler code:

```
myName = 'Jhon'
if myName == 'Jhon':
   print(myName * 5)
else:
   print('Hello')
```

Now, when you run this code (make sure to run it from a separate module, not from the interactive prompt), it will print 'Jhon' five times (note that Python will treat the objects exactly as they are specified, it won't even bother to try to convert the variable `myName`'s value to a number for multiplication) and that's it. This is because the code block inside of the if block is only executed. Note that if the `else` keyword was put anywhere but just below the if statement or if you had mixed the use of tabs and spaces, Python would raise an error.

Now, in your code,

```
for i in range(0,numClass):
    if breaks[i] == 0:
       classStart = 0
    else:
       classStart = dataList.index(breaks[i])
       classStart += 1
```

See, where the indent of `for`'s block of code starts? One tab, so, everything indented one tab after the `for` statement, will be inside of the for block. Now, obviously, the `if` statement is inside of the `for` statement, so it's inside the `for` statement. Now, let's move to next line, `classStart = 0` -- this is indented two tabs from the `for` statement and one tab from the `if` statement; so it's inside the `if` statement *and* inside the for block. Next line, you have an `else` keyword indented just one tab from the `for` statement but not two tabs, so it's inside the `for` statement, and *not* inside the `if` statement.

Consider putting curly-braces like these if you have coded in another language(s) before:

```
for i in range(0,numClass)
{
    if breaks[i] == 0
        {
        classStart = 0
        }
    else
        {
        classStart = dataList.index(breaks[i])
        classStart += 1
        }
}
```

The simple differences are that you are not required to put parenthesis for your expressions, unless, you want to force operator precedence rule and you don't need those curly braces, instead, just indent them equally.

Comment: This post was helpful, for someone used to Java trying to decipher Python, but just to be clear: you CANNOT use curly braces to delineate blocks of code in Python. Using curly braces will result in syntax errors. In Python, only use indentation to defining (i.e. delineate) the scope of code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,numClass):
    if breaks[i] == 0:
       classStart = 0
    else:
       classStart = dataList.index(breaks[i])
       classStart += 1
#   end if
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

That is right. In Python, the indentation delimitates your condition block, differently from e.g., Matlab, where you would have to insert an "end" to mark the block's end. I like both ways though!